# Ruby Rails Average two attributes in a query returning multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got two attributes I'm trying to average, but it's only averaging the second field here.  is there a way to do this?

```
 e = TiEntry.where('ext_trlid = ? AND mat_pidtc = ?', a.trlid, a.pidtc).average(:mat_mppss_rprcp && :mat_fppss_rprcp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e = TiEntry.where('ext_trlid = ? AND mat_pidtc = ?', a.trlid, a.pidtc).select("AVG(mat_mppss_rprcp) AS avg1, AVG(mat_fppss_rprcp) AS avg2").map { |i| [i.avg1, i.avg2] }
```

Is this working for you? it works as the average method does, but you can support as may values as you want

The advantage between this and the other queries here is this only uses one simple SQL query. The others fetch with an SQL everything in your table(can take some time if table is big) and then computes the average in ruby language

Answer (score -1):

I am sure that you have all ready looked at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average

But you cant get the average of 2 things.

what you can do not to repeat your query is:

```
 entries = TiEntry.where('ext_trlid = ? AND mat_pidtc = ?', a.trlid, a.pidtc)
 average_mppss = entries.average(:mat_mppss_rprcp)
 average_fppss = entries.average(:mat_fppss_rprcp)
```

this will only execute your query one time

I hope that this works for you